# How to integrate Google Analytics data in my pages?

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have a site that allows users to post their websites. I want to display some graphs from their Google Analytics account on my pages, showing traffic, visitors, etc.

I have seen this similar feature on Flippa

(https://flippa.com/3259993-reserve-met-pr-3-site-with-29-103-uniques-mo-making-avg-88-month-bin-bonus)

It asks you to authorize their account via OAuth2 (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/).

I've also seen Google Analytics Embed API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/), so I'm confused on which I should be using.

It seems using the Embed API is easiest, however, it only uses a client id. I want to show these pages publicly to everyone, so I will need an access token to request in behalf of the user right?

So here are my questions:

1. What exactly does each do? (Using Google Analytics Core Reporting API vs Embed API)
2. Can I use Embed API in my situation?
3. Embed API seems to already have built in graph and charting tools, do I have to re-implement those if I use Core Reporting API?

Let me know if I'm missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) It's not really a one or the other kind of thing. The Embed API actually uses the Core Reporting API under the hood to query data and display it on the page. You can think of the Embed API as kind of a wrapper on top of the Core Reporting API, making it easier to use from JavaScript.

2) If you have access to a [Google Analytics view](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649553?hl=en), then yes, you can use the Embed API to display data from that view. If you want to display data to users who don't have access to that view, then you'll have to authorize on their behalf. You can do that using the Embed API's `serverAuth` option. Here are the docs for that:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#auth

3) Again, these aren't two competing technologies. The Embed API uses the Core Reporting API under the hood. If you don't use the Embed API then yes you'll have to implement that stuff yourself.

Comment: I don't quite understand #2. So visitors won't really have access to the view, how do I authorize on their behalf? Do they need to be logged in to GA? I'm not actually sure how I'm supposed to use Embed API, if a user authorizes my client id, can I use that client id to show it to everyone else? Does it work like an access token?

Comment: Every access token belongs to a [Google project](https://console.developers.google.com/project) which will have a client ID as well as other access-level information. You can think of an access token as the result of an authorization request. Basically it says: this project will grant access to this user for X amount of time as long as they use this token.

Comment: Re #2: in order to make a request to the Core Reporting API *someone* needs to request access and gain an access token. The Embed API usually allows the visitor to the site to do this via a Google Sign-in flow. However, if *you* have access to the view, you can get an access token yourself on the back end. Then you can use the `serverAuth` option with the Embed API, which essentially just lets it know that you've already taken care of auth yourself.

Comment: Does the Embed API allow you to retrieve access tokens when user authorizes? (so I can save them on the back end probably with the refresh token to make requests on behalf of the user instead of re-authorizing users)? It's weird if it doesn't, I'm not sure what Embed API is for if the user is always required to re-authorize and will only be able to view his own web properties.

Comment: It does, but only after visitors to your site have authorized, which you said you didn't want to force them to do. You said you wanted to authorize on their behalf, which you can if you also have access to the view you want to show them. All you need is an access token.

Comment: Just one last question, I'm already able to retrieve the access and refresh token from users who authorize (website owners who give me access to their GA data). And I can use serverAuth.access_token to use the retrieved tokens, but I see it's displayed on the client side (JS), would it be a security issue?

Comment: It should be fine. Note though that you can only pass the access token to `serverAuth` (not the refresh token). The access token expires after 60 minutes, so it's generally not a big deal if people see that. The refresh token, however, should not go in user-visible code.